# MapKit Zooming Issues

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

I have a map in my app that start as a small map and becomes large after the user clicks it.

Here it is in iOS 10 and iOS 11 side by side (small)

[image]

When the user taps the map, it becomes full screen and appears as such (again iOS 10 - iOS 11):

[image]

AS you can see, in iOS 11 it seems to zoom in for some reason.

Here is the function related to tapping the map:

```
@objc fileprivate func mapTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.mapViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.height + 2
    self.mapViewToTop.constant = -73
    self.mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    UIApplication.shared.hideStatusBar(false)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.scrollView.layer.zPosition = 10
    }, completion: {
        done in
        self.mapXButtonTrailing.constant = 20
        self.mapXButton.layer.zPosition = 11
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)})

}
```

And finally: Clicking the X button and undoing the above results in:
[image]

This is slightly different then when it was initially in the small state, as the iOS 11 version has again done something with the zoom/set region by becoming slightly zoomed out.

I should note, that to make the initial small load of the map render the same region correctly for iOS 11 and iOS 10 I had to do the following:

```
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        self.region.center = location
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
            self.region.span.latitudeDelta = delta
            self.region.span.longitudeDelta = delta
        }else{
            self.region.span.latitudeDelta = delta * 3.5
            self.region.span.longitudeDelta = delta * 3.5
        }
```

The iOS 11 version once again has something occurring different then how I used to have it for iOS 10.